# AWS Cli sync with non DNS compatible bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, botocore

Is there any way to use AWS command line to sync a local folder with a bucket that contains periods '.'?

If I do this:

```
aws s3 sync local_folder/ s3://files.domain.com/backup
```

I get this error:

> fatal error: Bucket named files.domain.com is not DNS compatible.
>   Virtual hosted-style addressing cannot be used. The addressing style
>   can be configured by removing the addressing_style value or setting
>   that value to 'path' or 'auto' in the AWS Config file or in the
>   botocore.client.Config object.

I already tried removing or changing the `addressing_style` value in the AWS config, but didn't work. I have no idea how to change on botocore.

**AWS Config**

```
[default]
output = json
region = us-west-1
s3 =
  max_concurrent_requests = 100
  max_queue_size = 10000
  multipart_threshold = 64MB
  multipart_chunksize = 16MB
  use_accelerate_endpoint = true
```

Comment: The bucket is in us-west-1

Comment: I have edited the question to add the current AWS config.

Comment: Does it raise exception even when `region` info is provided? Also can you add the `addressing_style = path` along with region to the config. Just a guess, add `--no-verify-ssl true` to the command.

Comment: Same error message.

Comment: Could you retry with v4 signing? Set signature_version to s3v4.

Comment: @jarmod, no luck. Same error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems I found the problem.

```
use_accelerate_endpoint = true
```

Transfer acceleration is not supported for buckets with periods (.) in their names: [Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html).

This means that `use_accelerate_endpoint` must be removed or set to false. Otherwise, it won't work and will throw that error, making you think it can work with the right settings, when in fact you need to remove the flag.