# AWS CLI S3 Sync Still Fails When Bucket Is Not Compatible After Using Recommended Config

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, botocore

When trying:

```
aws s3 sync --delete site/ s3://site.domain.com
```

I receive the error:

> fatal error: Bucket named site.domain.com is not DNS compatible. Virtual hosted-style addressing cannot be used. The addressing style can be configured by removing the addressing_style value or setting that value to 'path' or 'auto' in the AWS Config file or in the botocore.client.Config object.

I have changed the addressing style and disabled the accelerated endpoint in my AWS config using `aws configure set default.s3.addressing_style path` and `aws configure set default.s3.use_accelerate_endpoint false`, but I still receive the same error.

Full config file here:

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json
s3 =
    use_accelerate_endpoint = false
    addressing_style = path
```

Software versions here:

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.15.28 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/16.6.0 botocore/1.10.28
```

Comment: What command are you trying to issue, eg: `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 ls`? Your command does not have an actual action in it.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you for catching that. Edited question to show that I am trying to `aws s3 sync`

Comment: Are you using the correct bucket name ? Could you try an `aws s3 ls` ?

Comment: Let's start from the very beginning. Remove the `s3` settings in the `config` file. Then,  try to list all buckets (`aws s3 ls`). If that works, try to list a specific bucket (`aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket`). If that works, try copying a file to the bucket (`aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://my-bucket/foo.txt`). If that works, try `aws s3 sync`. If you are using a domain name (`site.domain.com`), make sure that this is the exact name of your bucket, too.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I've removed the S3 settings from the config file. `aws s3 ls` and `aws s3 ls s3://most-buckets` complete successfully, however `aws s3 ls s3://site.domain.com` also gives the error `Bucket named site.domain.com is not DNS compatible. Virtual hosted-style addressing cannot be used...`

Comment: Great! First, confirm that your bucket is actually named `site.domain.com` to match the command (that is, it matches the _full name_ of the bucket you created). Second, try addressing the specific region where the bucket is stored by adding `--region <region-name>` just in case that matters. Next, I'd try `aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket <bucket-name>` to see if that command is any happier. See also: [AWS Cli sync with non DNS compatible bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41795555/174777)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I can confirm that the bucket name matches the argument I've supplied to the command. Adding `--region us-east-1` fails, and `aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket site.domain.com` also fails. I've also deleted my `~/.aws/config` file to no avail. For what it's worth, my colleague can execute the exact same command successfully.

Comment: Ah! So you're saying that somebody else can run the same command successfully, and it is only failing for you? Then this is no longer an AWS issue, it is something to do with the setup on your computer. That's something for _you_ to debug.