# S3 Batch operation is slow for copying s3 objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-batch

I am trying to copy objects b/w s3 buckets using S3 batch operation. Both buckets are in same region but different account. I followed this blog and set up the inventory/role/policies.

[S3 batch operation blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/cross-account-bulk-transfer-of-files-using-amazon-s3-batch-operations/)

**I found that S3 batch operation is dead slow**. Below is my source bucket stats:

```
Bucket size: 2.7 TB.

Number of objects: 169 Million
```

**In 14 hours, it copied only 20% objects**

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: if this works https://stackoverflow.com/q/39149171/13126651

Comment: You can also use [S3 replication for exisiing objects](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/replicating-existing-objects-between-s3-buckets/).